# What should i put in DLL when using it to create global hook?

Tags: c++, dll, keyboard-hook

I'm creating a global hook but the problem is that it needs a DLL but i don't know anything about DLL. So what should i include in the dll file?

Answer (score 0):

You can register as a low level keyboard hook, then you don't have to create a dll.

If you have never created a DLL before, I would suggest starting with something other than a global hook. Maybe a simple tutorial like [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855), [this](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/4877) or [this](http://www.icynorth.com/development/createdlltutorial.html)...